# How can I keep the header and footer the same in components and content will be changed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

I am a beginner in web development. I can use PHP server sides scripting.

I have the following design:

1. Pages 5
2. All have the same header and footer

Is it possible to keep the header as well as the footer in different files so that every page will use the header/footer as components.

Comment: [PHP.net is awesome](http://www.php.net). Simply use the site for any questions you have, you should really have a look at [include()](http://www.php.net/include)... *protip* you can type any PHP function after php.net/ and it will give you that functions page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use php [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function.

You can write something like this. This header and footer will be constant for your all the 5 page. and in each page you can change your code.

```
<?php
include '/Path/To/header.php';
// Here you can write your page script without header and footer.
include '/Path/To/footer.php';
?>
```